# Haskell add a UTCTime to a custom data attribute

Tags: haskell

I need a help on how I can use a `do` block (to perform IO) in the follow
function. Bassicaly I have a `Entry` like:

```
data Entry = Entry
  { entryHeader :: String
  , entryBody :: Maybe T.Text
  , entryTags :: [String]
  , entryTime :: UTCTime
  } deriving (Generic, Show, Eq, Ord)
```

And the follow functions:

```
getNow :: IO UTCTime
getNow = do
  now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
  pure now


buildNewItem :: TuidoState -> TuidoState
buildNewItem s =
  do
    now <- getNow
    let nextID = 10 
        headerTitle = head $ BE.getEditContents $ _theEdit s
        newEntry = Entry { entryHeader = headerTitle
                         , entryBody = Just ("Test")
                         , entryTime = now <------ how use getNow here.
                         , entryTags = [headerTitle]
                       }
      actualEntries = (_entries s)
  in if headerTitle /= ""
     then s { _entries = BL.listInsert 0 newEntry actualEntries }
     else s
```

Of course, it does not work, I have problems understanding how I need to arrange my code to deal with pure and impure functions, and how to put it together.

Some help here? I'm accepting the suggestion of readings regarding this subject too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To start, in order to use an IO action like `getNow`, you need to be in an IO context, e.g. something like `buildNewItem :: TuidoState -> IO TuidoState`. Then, you usually want to `let x = ...` when you call non-IO functions, and `x <- ...` when you call IO functions. Maybe you are already doing that correctly, I can't tell.

Comment: What is `getNow` doing for you that `getCurrentTime` is not? (Spoilers: this is a trick question. They are completely identical in all but name.)

Comment: `in` must be indented more than its `let` is indented.

Comment: another possibility is to omit that `in` altogether, but then that `if`  after it must start at exactly the same indentation as `let` above it (and `then` and `else` must both be indented more than the `if`). see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info.

Answer (score 1):

Simply admit, as `getCurrentTime` and `getNow` do, that you are doing `IO`:

```
buildNewItem :: TuidoState -> IO TuidoState
...
  in pure $ if ...
```

Comment: with this fix applied, the code will still not work.

Comment: @WillNess The clarion call of the StackOverflow question is for help fixing one problem that can't be understood (by the asker, at least). Then it is the asker's responsibility to make progress on their own for a while.

Comment: this reminds me yet again of that answer of mine which gave the OP full working solution to their problem and left making the small remaining change on their own to the code to make it optimal. just like you say it is ought to be done on SO. I really don't understand why I should get the opposite treatment from you for doing the exact same  thing as  you are doing here and elsewhere, even claiming it to be The Right Thing to do (which was my position from the get go). this seems wantonly unfair. I really am at a loss.

Comment: (IOW you say it here, but you seem to have said - and acted - the exact opposite there).

Comment: @WillNess I don't see any contradiction yet. Suggesting new, bad code to get somebody over a hump is different from correcting only the hump in existing bad code.

Comment: the code (the algorithm behind it) was excellent, after removing small wart. which I wanted for them to realize, to not deprive them of that a-ha moment. the answer explicitly said (even in its 1st version) that there's a change to be made to make it efficient. this how I write answers to newbies. I don't give them ready-made solution 2 levels above their head out of the blue. I don;t consider _that_ helpful at all.

Comment: for now I've applied your own standard to your recent answers, as I've understood it.

Comment: this just occurred to me: you said: "The clarion call of the StackOverflow question is for help fixing one problem .... Then it is the asker's responsibility to make progress on their own" **exactly** as I did in that answer. **exactly**. this is just ridiculous. (and you did it once before, but there I've put it aside. here it's just too much)